# passing parameters to batch from java works but without result

Tags: java, batch-file, bazaar

I'm trying to add version control to my web server (on windows, I know...) and I need to use a batch script to do automatic adds and commits. Here is what I have now :

```
public static void bzr_add(String path, String commit) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(scripts + "bzr_add.bat", storage, path, "\"" + commit + "\"");
    Process p = pb.start();
    String line;
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    r.close();
    try {
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(local.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

With "scripts" being the directory where the script can be found, "storage" the storage directory and "path" the path of the new file.

The batch script :

```
cd %1
bzr add %2
bzr commit -m %3
```

And what I obtain :

```
Infos: C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish\domains\domain1>cd c:\storage_dir\ 
Infos: C:\storage_dir>bzr add dir\file.ext 
Infos: C:\storage_dir>bzr commit -m "commit_message"
```

So it seems ok, and when I copy this in the cmd shell it works (it also works when I do bzr_add.bat par1 par2 par3 in the shell). And if I modify the script to create new files, they are created in the correct directory so something is executed correctly.

But bazaar doesn't seem to agree on that when I execute the script through java, any guesses ?

Comment: Can you explain what's the actual problem for you? What do you mean by "But bazaar doesn't seem to agree on that"?

Comment: Do you see any errors? Maybe also check the log file <user home>/.bzr.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my own question (although I don't know why I needed to do this).

I have to add this line to my batch file :

```
path = %PATH%;c:\Program Files\Bazaar\
```

It's weird because it's already in the path when I use cmd.exe, but it works that way.
Maybe it will help someone with the same problem.

Comment: most likely your Java environment is different from cmd.exe environment.